# String gets destroyed in if statement using in operator in Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, python-3.4, in-operator

I have the following problem with the following Python code:

```
katalog = open(r"Katalog.txt", 'r')
katentrylist = open(r"katentrylist.txt", 'r')

for line in katalog:

    for element in katentrylist:
        if element in line:
            print(element)
            if clean6.search(element) != None:
                element = clean6.sub('', element)
            if clean7.search(element) != None:
                element = clean7.sub('', element)
            if clean8.search(element) != None:
                element = clean8.sub('', element)
            if clean9.search(element) != None:
                element = clean9.sub('', element)
            elementtxt = element + '.txt'
            with open(elementtxt, 'a') as d:
                d.writelines(line)
                d.close()

    elementtxt = ''
    check = ''
```

When I try to execute the print(element) statement the variable element is empty after the if-Statement using the in operator. It is however possible for me to do a print-statement of the line variable or to print a random string. If I use any other if-statement which is true, not using the in operator it is also possible for me to print the element varibale.

Does someone have an explanation for this behavior and can give me a hint why this happens.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: At a glance, `katentrylist` is not a list, and it's dangerous to treat it like one. IIRC, you can only iterate over a file object exactly once, and then it is exhausted. So putting `for element in katentrylist` inside another `for` loop, means that you will only get your expected elements the first time around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The behavior also occurs when I use a list instead of the katentrylist file. During debugging I have just changed it.

Comment: Hmm, what type is `clean6`? a pattern returned by `re.compile`? Something else?

Comment: It is this pattern: 'code' clean6 = compile('\\n')

Comment: I see. Well, I don't see anything wrong with the code here that would make `print(element)` fail. It may be necessary to compose an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so potential answerers can replicate the behavior on their own machines.